# HTML clickable area for div that is outside of divs bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onsen-ui

I have this table structure, where all the columns have a different click method to them. The first column is not so wide, so it's pretty hard to click on it in a mobile browser, but i want to keep it like that, because of the borders.

Is there a way, where the clickable area of the first column could overlap invisibly the second column?

Here's a picture where I try to show what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

Here is the HTML (note i'm using special row and column elements because of the onsen UI i'm wrapping my application in)

```
<ons-row>
    <ons-col class="firstcolumn" width="32px">
        <div class="item-thum" style="width:60px;" ng-click="confirm(item, item.id)">
            <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; padding-left: 3px;">
                <ons-icon size="30px" icon="ok"></ons-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col ng-click="Details(item, item.id)" class="secondcolumn">
        <div class="titlediv">
            <header>
                <span class="item-title">{{item.name}}</span>
            </header>
        </div>              
    </ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

You can see that in my current code the **col2** has an click event handler which always fires if i click anywhere near the second column.

Comment: Hmm, you probably have to play a bit with positioning on the icon, a fixed width, a transparent background for the icon wrapper, overflow for the col1 and a z-index. The 'alternative' approach for mobile would be to change  both columns to 100% width blocks and have them underneath eachother, effectviely making them rows instead of columns, which would completely remove your problem.

Comment: Post your css for `.firstcolumn .item-thum .titlediv .secondcolumn` please.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to:

1. Give the first col a greater z-index then the second col

   ```
   .firstcolumn{
       z-index : 2;
   }

   .secondcolumn{
       z-index : 1;
   }
   ```
2. Extend the padding-right of col1 to cover the bit of col2 you want to be clickable for col1.

I think that's most of the work you would have to do, let me know how it goes.

EDIT: Point 2 might not be needed/appropriate as per the comments below.

Comment: In point 2 you probably meant `padding-right` instead of left. Actually doing that will move the border, which is not what the user wants. However he's already set the proper widths so point 1 should be sufficient. __Sidenote:__ Usually when setting `z-index`es it's recommended to set `position: relative` or sth similar, as otherwise they may not work. It may not be needed in this case, but it's still something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a quick play with w3schools TryIt editor and have come up with the following as a start:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style type="text/css">

table td {
 position:relative;
 border:1px solid black;
 height:20px;
 width:200px;
}
.overLap {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:150%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(51,204,51,0.3);
}
.shorter {
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <div class="overLap"></div>
    <p>Data 1</p>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="shorter"></div>
    <p>Data 2</p>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Its pretty basic and just shows that each table cell contains a div which is sized according to the click space you want. The onclick would then be assigned to each div.